# Cast elements on an array of unknown types by using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, casting

I have a Dictionary object where the **Keys** are of type string and the **Values** are of type object because they are extracted from a file where the data type (for column) might differ.

```
Dictionary<string, object[]> lfileContent;
```

I would like to get the type of every array and casting the type. Of course I cannot do it while they are in the Dictionary but when I extract each **Value** to use them. For instance (I use a pseudocode C# using a logical approach):

```
ltype = lfileContent["key1"].Value.GetType();
ltype newarray = (ltype) fileContent["key1"].Value;
```

I would like to make three questions:

1) When I get the elements from the file and store them as **object**, will they keep the information that reflection uses to get their type?

2) If (1) does not apply, shall I use reflection to get their type when I extract them from the file (before inserting as **object** in the Dictionary)?

3) How can I make such casting by using reflection?

Thanks

Francesco

Comment: How does it make sense to want to cast an object to a type that you do not know at compile time?

Comment: @Kirk Woll - The only thing I can think of is that he wants intellisense or something on the item; which for a runtime type is near impossible. @Francesco; the objects are already of the type they are; you don't need to cast them.

Comment: @Tejs: thanks for the answer. It makes sense to cast the type because I get the data from an Excel file. In the Excel file the first row represent the Dictionary Keys, and each column the Dictionary Values (an array of type T). I do not know this type in advance because I am not guaranteed the data in the Excel are always the same (I just know first row = Keys others = Values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Reflection, but the object will retain the type info.  To cast the object to a type you have to tell it which type at compile time, you could use Reflection to dynamically manipulate the object, but that's different than casting it as a type.  I would use something like this:

```
string[] stringArray = fileContent["Key1"].Value as string[];
if (stringArray != null) {
    // the object is a string[] type, it is safe to use the stringArray variable
}

// and continue for other types that may be stored in the dictionary
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. So if I have N types possible you suggest me to use a Switch construct with N cases?